# Parse Error: Unexpected token: LoginRoute

Tags: reactjs, wasp-lang

I'm new to React and wasp. I have a wasp project using React. When I run the command `wasp db migrate-dev` I'm getting the error below. The syntax looks correct and the import statement as well. My wasp version is the latest - 0.13. Not sure what's causing the issue.

```
❌ --- [Error] Your wasp project failed to compile: -------------------------------

- /Users/administrator/Documents/Code/AI/brandy-so4fq/main.wasp @ 22:9-18
  Parse error:
    Unexpected token: LoginRoute
    Expected one of the following tokens instead: ':'

      21 |   },
      22 |   route LoginRoute { path: "/login", to: LoginPage }
      23 |   page LoginPage {
- /Users/administrator/Documents/Code/AI/brandy-so4fq/main.wasp @ 22:20
  Parse error:
    Unexpected token: {
    Expected one of the following tokens instead: <identifier>

      21 |   },
      22 |   route LoginRoute { path: "/login", to: LoginPage }
      23 |   page LoginPage {
- /Users/administrator/Documents/Code/AI/brandy-so4fq/main.wasp @ 22:26
  Parse error:
    Unexpected token: :
    Expected one of the following tokens instead: <identifier>

      21 |   },
      22 |   route LoginRoute { path: "/login", to: LoginPage }
      23 |   page LoginPage {
- /Users/administrator/Documents/Code/AI/brandy-so4fq/main.wasp @ 22:28-35
  Parse error:
    Unexpected token: "/login"
    Expected one of the following tokens instead: <identifier>,<eof>

      21 |   },
      22 |   route LoginRoute { path: "/login", to: LoginPage }
      23 |   page LoginPage {
- /Users/administrator/Documents/Code/AI/brandy-so4fq/main.wasp @ 22:36
  Parse error:
    Unexpected token: ,
    Expected one of the following tokens instead: <eof>

      21 |   },
      22 |   route LoginRoute { path: "/login", to: LoginPage }
      23 |   page LoginPage {


❌ --- [Error] Compilation of wasp project failed: --------------------------------

5 errors found
```

Here's my project setup.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLbm2.png)

Here's the Login page code.

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { LoginForm } from "wasp/client/auth";

export default function Login() {
  return (
    <div className="w-full h-full bg-white">
      <div className="min-w-full min-h-[75vh] flex items-center justify-center">
        <div className="w-full h-full max-w-sm p-5 bg-white">
          <div>
            <LoginForm
              appearance={{
                colors: {
                  brand: 'var(--auth-form-brand)',
                  brandAccent: 'var(--auth-form-brand-accent)',
                  submitButtonText: 'var(--auth-form-submit-button-text-color)',
                }
              }}
            />
            <div className="mt-4 text-center">
              If you don't have an account go to{" "}
              <Link to="/signup" className="text-primary-500 hover:text-primary-800 underline">
                sign up
              </Link>
              .
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's my main code.

```
app brandy {
  wasp: {
    version: "^0.13.0"
  },
  title: "brandy",
  client: {
    rootComponent: import { Layout } from "@src/Layout.jsx",
  },
  db: {
    prisma: {
      clientPreviewFeatures: ["extendedWhereUnique"]
    }
  },
  auth: {
    userEntity: User,
    methods: {
      usernameAndPassword: {}
    },
    onAuthFailedRedirectTo: "/login",
    onAuthSucceededRedirectTo: "/"
  },
  route LoginRoute { path: "/login", to: LoginPage }
  page LoginPage {
    component: import Login from "@src/pages/auth/Login.jsx"
  }
  route SignupRoute { path: "/signup", to: SignupPage }
  page SignupPage {
    component: import Signup from "@src/pages/auth/Signup.jsx"
  }
  entity User {=psl
    id       Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
    chickens Chicken[]
  psl=}
  entity Chicken {=psl
    id       Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
    userId   Int
    punches  Int    @default(0)
    movement String
    user     User   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  psl=}
  action createChicken {
    fn: import { createChicken } from "@src/actions.js",
    entities: [Chicken]
  }
  action updateChicken {
    fn: import { updateChicken } from "@src/actions.js",
    entities: [Chicken]
  }
  action incrementPunches {
    fn: import { incrementPunches } from "@src/actions.js",
    entities: [Chicken]
  }
  query getUserChickens {
    fn: import { getUserChickens } from "@src/queries.js",
    entities: [User, Chicken]
  }
  query getChicken {
    fn: import { getChicken } from "@src/queries.js",
    entities: [Chicken]
  }
  route ChickenCreateRoute { path: "/chicken/create", to: ChickenCreatePage }
  page ChickenCreatePage {
    component: import ChickenCreatePage from "@src/pages/ChickenCreate.jsx",
    authRequired: true
  }
  route ChickenListRoute { path: "/chickens", to: ChickenListPage }
  page ChickenListPage {
    component: import ChickenListPage from "@src/pages/ChickenList.jsx",
    authRequired: true
  }
  route ChickenDetailRoute { path: "/chicken/:chickenId", to: ChickenDetailPage }
  page ChickenDetailPage {
    component: import ChickenDetail from "@src/pages/ChickenDetail.jsx",
    authRequired: true
  }
  route DashboardRoute { path: "/", to: DashboardPage }
  page DashboardPage {
    component: import DashboardPage from "@src/pages/Dashboard.jsx",
    authRequired: true
  }
}
```

I have the latest version of Node. I don't think Node version is the issue.

```
{
  npm: '10.5.0',
  node: '21.7.1',
  acorn: '8.11.3',
  ada: '2.7.6',
  ares: '1.27.0',
  base64: '0.5.2',
  brotli: '1.1.0',
  cjs_module_lexer: '1.2.2',
  cldr: '44.1',
  icu: '74.2',
  llhttp: '9.1.3',
  modules: '120',
  napi: '9',
  nghttp2: '1.60.0',
  nghttp3: '0.7.0',
  ngtcp2: '1.3.0',
  openssl: '3.0.13+quic',
  simdjson: '3.7.0',
  simdutf: '4.0.8',
  tz: '2024a',
  undici: '6.6.2',
  unicode: '15.1',
  uv: '1.48.0',
  uvwasi: '0.0.20',
  v8: '11.8.172.17-node.20',
  zlib: '1.3.0.1-motley-40e35a7'
}
```

Comment: What is wasp? Thst doesn’t look like react code